# To which person "who" refers in the following sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

*J* sits third to the left of *G*, **who** likes grapes.

In the above sentence, to whom does **who** refers – *J* or *G*?

This is the first time I've encountered an ambiguous situation related to using "who." Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ambiguity. 'Who' refers to its last preceding noun, which is G. If J and not G liked grapes, you might write this: "J, who sits third to the left of G, likes grapes."

1. Mary sits near Joe, who is team leader. This sentence tells us: Mary sits near Joe; the team leader is Joe.
2. Mary, who sits near Joe, is team leader. This sentence tells us: Mary sits near Joe; the team leader is Mary.